# I Can't Install or Remove Any Application

Tags: apt, software-center, dpkg, aptitude

when i try to install or remove an application via either software center or apt-get install they both fail and give some debconf errors below is the log please help.Sorry some of the text is not english.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti
Bağımlılık ağacı inşa ediliyor.       
Durum bilgisi okunuyor... Bitti       
Aşağıdaki ek paketler de yüklenecek:
  aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.49.0 libcwidget3
Önerilen paketler:
  aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc tasksel debtags libcwidget-dev
Aşağıdaki YENİ paketler kurulacak:
  aptitude aptitude-common libboost-iostreams1.49.0 libcwidget3
Yükseltilen: 0, Yeni Kurulan: 4, Kaldırılacak: 0 ve Yükseltilmeyecek: 48.
8 tam olarak kurulmadı veya kaldırılmadı.
İndirilmesi gereken dosya boyutu 0 B/2.498 kB
Bu işlemden sonra 10,4 MB ek disk alanı kullanılacak.
Devam etmek istiyor musunuz [E/h]? e
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude-common.
dpkg: uyarı: files list file for package 'aspell' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: uyarı: files list file for package 'ubuntu-desktop' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: uyarı: files list file for package 'vuze' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: uyarı: files list file for package 'java-wrappers' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Veritabanı okunuyor... 198988 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking aptitude-common (from .../aptitude-common_0.6.8.1-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-iostreams1.49.0.
Unpacking libboost-iostreams1.49.0 (from .../libboost-iostreams1.49.0_1.49.0-3.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcwidget3.
Unpacking libcwidget3 (from .../libcwidget3_0.5.16-3.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aptitude.
Unpacking aptitude (from .../aptitude_0.6.8.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
wicd-daemon (1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) kuruluyor...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
dpkg: error processing wicd-daemon (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alt işlemi çıkış durumunda hata döndürdü : 1
man-db (2.6.3-1) kuruluyor...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alt işlemi çıkış durumunda hata döndürdü : 1
dictionaries-common (1.12.10) kuruluyor...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :Böyle bir dosya ya da dizin yok
dpkg: error processing dictionaries-common (--configure):
 installed post-installation script alt işlemi çıkış durumunda hata döndürdü : 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell:
 aspell depends on dictionaries-common (>> 0.40); bununla beraber:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing aspell (--configure):
 bağımlılık sorunları - yapılandırılmadan bırakılıyor
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aspell-en:
 aspell-en depends on aspell (>= 0.60.3-2); bununla beraber:
  Package aspell is not configured yet.
 aspell-en depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2); bununla beraber:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing aspell-en (--configure):
 bağımlılık sorunları - yapılandırılmadan bırakılıyor
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hyphen-en-us:
 hyphen-en-us depends on dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) | openoffice.org-updatedicts; bununla beraber:
  Package dictionaries-common is not configured yet.
  openoffice.org-updatedicts paketi yüklenmedi.
  Package dictionaries-common which provides openoffice.org-updatedicts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing hyphen-en-us (--configure):
 bağımlılık sorunları - yapılandırılmadan bırakılıyor
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wicd-gtk:
 wicd-gtk depends on wicd-daemon (= 1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1); bununla beraber:
  Package wicd-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing wicd-gtk (--configure):
 bağımlılık sorunları - yapılandırılmadan bırakılıyor
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wicd:
 wicd depends on wicd-daemon (= 1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1); bununla beraber:
  Package wicd-daemon is not configured yet.
 wicd depends on wicd-gtk (= 1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) | wicd-curses (= 1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) | wicd-cli (= 1.7.2.4-2ubuntu1) | wicd-client; bununla beraber:
  Package wicd-gtk is not configured yet.
  wicd-curses paketi yüklenmedi.
  wicd-cli paketi yüklenmedi.
  wicd-client paketi yüklenmedi.
  Package wicd-gtk which provides wicd-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing wicd (--configure):
 bağımlılık sorunları - yapılandırılmadan bırakılıyor
aptitude-common (0.6.8.1-2ubuntu1) kuruluyor...
libboost-iostreams1.49.0 (1.49.0-3.1ubuntu1) kuruluyor...
libcwidget3 (0.5.16-3.4ubuntu1) kuruluyor...
aptitude (0.6.8.1-2ubuntu1) kuruluyor...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/aptitude-curses to provide /usr/bin/aptitude (aptitude) in Otomatik Mod
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
İşlem sırasında hatalar bulundu:
 wicd-daemon
 man-db
 dictionaries-common
 aspell
 aspell-en
 hyphen-en-us
 wicd-gtk
 wicd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install debconf --reinstall
```

Comment: And next try `sudo apt-get install -f`